# Replicate each element in a vector different times in R

Tags: r, vector, rep

Suppose I have a numeric vector `v`

```
v <- 1:5
```

I want to 
`rep`

`v[1]` by `v[1]` times.

`v[2]` by `v[2]` times... and so on....

The desired output would be:

```
1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5
```

The following does not work. Got any ideas?

```
rep(v, each = function(x) v[x])
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

We can use `rep` on itself

```
rep(v, v)
```

If we want to specify the argument, use `times`

```
rep(v, times = v)
```

The `each` would not take anonymous function and it takes only a vector of length 1.  According to `?rep`

> each - non-negative integer. Each element of x is repeated each times. Other inputs will be coerced to an integer or double vector and the first element taken. Treated as 1 if NA or invalid.